# jQuery Datepicker BeforeShowDay Second Parameter

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

jQuery's datepicker allows you to highlight dates using the BeforeShowDay callback.

Is it possible to pass a second parameter to the method?

```
$(selector).datepicker({beforeShowDay: selectedDay});   

function selectedDay(date) {

    // Do stuff

    return [true, 'class_name'];
}
```

As you can see, the parameter `date` is automatically passed to the selectedDay method, thus making me unsure as to how to pass a second parameter.

Cheers.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
function selectedDay(date, param ) {
     // Do stuff with param
     return [true, ''];
}

function doStuff(){
    var param = "param_to_pass";
    $(selector).datepicker({
        beforeShowDay: function (date){
            return selectedDay(date, param );
        }
    }); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you can just create another function and pass any params you want:

```
function foo (param) { ... }
function selectedDay (date) {
  foo(param);
  return [true, 'class_name'];
}

$(selector).datepicker({beforeShowDay: selectedDay});
```

Comment: Hi. I get what you're saying, but I'd still need to pass `param` in to the `selectDay` function.

Answer (score 0):

You can write a function which returns an array of dates

```
function selectedDay(date1,date2) {
// your code
return dates[];
}
```

and then

```
$(selector).datepicker({beforeShowDay: selectedDay});
```

just an idea, absolutely not sure if it works

Answer (score 0):

I resorted to not-the-best-practice to solve my issue. I simply made the second parameter to pass a global. It'll do the job for the time being.

```
$(selector).datepicker({beforeShowDay: selectedDay});   

var my_param = x;
function selectedDay(date) {

    // Do stuff, use my_param

    return [true, 'class_name'];
}
```