# jQuery datepicker beforeShowDay issue

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-datepicker

I ran into a problem where on beforeShowDay, I need to call a function and at the same time set the noweekends.

```
beforeShowDay: $j.datepicker.noWeekends, functionHandler;

function functionHandler(){
   // do stuff
}
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/VntM3/48/)

How to manage these two things together?

Any pointers will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Why not set it inside `functionHandler`?

Comment: I have edited my question; I have put it inside the function but then it's not working. see js fiddle attached in the question

Comment: Maybe this http://stackoverflow.com/a/13514816/1793718 could help